# Why is $3^n$ = $2^{O(n)}$?

Tags: asymptotics

I read that  $3^n$ = $2^{O(n)}$. But shouldnt having a base 3 be exponentially larger than having a base 2 ?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**
$$
a^n = b^{\log_{b}(a^n)} = b^{(\log_b a) \cdot n}
$$

Comment: Another way of looking at it is this: $2^n\leq 3^n\leq 2^{2n}\ (=4^n)$, so some number $x$ between $n$ and $2n$ gives $3^n=2^x$. The bounds $n\leq x\leq 2n$ ensure that $x=O(n)$.